# How to copy a file to a directory in Java 7

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to copy a number of files to an output directory in Java 7 using Path and Files. This doesn't work:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("/my/file.txt"), Paths.get("/my/output/directory/");
```

It generates a "directory not empty" error.

Yes, I could write code to name the output file directly, or use Guava, but I'm trying to do it the simplest way using the new Java 7 nio classes.

Comment: Why don't you want to write `Files.copy(Paths.get("/my/file.txt"), Paths.get("/my/output/directory/file.txt");` ?  It's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way:

```
Path file = /* path to source file */
Path to = /* path to destination directory */
Files.copy(file, to.resolve(file.getFileName()));
```

Answer (score 7):

The command appears to be attempting to replace the directory itself. Try specifying the filename in the target directory

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("/my/file.txt"), Paths.get("/my/output/directory/file.txt"));
```

Comment: I could do that, but I have a large number of files and one output directory, so it's more convenient just to specify the directory, just as you do when doing an operating system file copy.

Comment: Why is it more convenient?  You're in a loop anyway.  How much code to you really need to add to grab the "name" part of the file's path, and tack it onto the directory?

Answer (score 4):

From docs [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move):

> copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
>
> Copy a file to a target **file**.

So you must specify destination file.

> I have a large number of files

You can get file name by splitting source path and append to destination folder.